# Would a 53 cm track(cinelli mash bolt) frame fit a 6'0" tall guy?

Tags: frames

I want to buy a friends but I'm not sure it will fit me

Comment: Voted to close as not constructive, but I think this is indeed a dupe of the question that @Tom77 indicated.

Comment: How could anyone even guess knowing only your height? Two people of the same height can easily be several centimeters different in leg length.

Answer (score 0):

Probably going to fit a bit small, but you may be able to make it work.  Try it out, jack the seat up a lot.  My guess is that you'll feel a bit 'smashed' due to the top tube not being long enough.  Might be able to compensate with a setback seatpost and/or a longer stem.